# How to make aws crawler recognize new partition structure in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, google-crawlers

I have the structure below in the s3:
`s3://landing-zone/api/report/task=log-results/year=2022/month=1/day=1/hour=0/minute=18/file.csv`

I want to store all the new files just until hour like:
`s3://landing-zone/api/report/task=log-results/year=2022/month=1/day=1/hour=0/file.csv`

I tried adding the new files just until hour folder but the aws crawler can't get these new files available to athena.
What is the best way to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have partitions `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour` and `minute` in the Athena table. Let's say it is `tableA`. You can create a `tableB` with exactly the same schema but using partitions `year`, `month`, `day` and `hour`. Then you do an [INSERT AS A SELECT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html) for each 60 minutes to group rows of 1 hour.

```
INSERT INTO tableB 
SELECT col1, col2, SUM(col3)
FROM tableA
GROUP BY col3 <ONLY 60 MINUTES TO GATHER 1 HOUR>;
```

You will need to do one insert for each 60 minutes. In the end you will get S3 buckets for `tableB` smaller than `tableA`.